# Preserving Linebreaks in textarea.value

Tags: javascript

I have to use textarea.value text but it does not preserve line breaks as input by the user. I don't want to use `replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />')` trick as it is useful only to render text as html.

Is there any other way to access textarea.value as it is?

Comment: BTW: Shouldn't it be `replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Gy7W3/, the text area is returning a linefeed character on the `.value` property everywhere the user enters a line break so it seems to already do what you want.